# Visual Basic Shift Cipher

Tags: vb.net, encryption, modulo, shift

I have a problem with my Ceasar shift cipher program. The code works fine when i have to encrypt some text with n shift ciphers. But when i want to decrypt some text, the array index goes negative and i get an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim alfabet() As Char = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "æ", "ø", "å"}


Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub



Private Sub btnKod_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnKod.Click

    Kod(txtDekodet.Text, txtTrylletal.Text, True)

End Sub


Private Sub btnDekod_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDekod.Click

    Kod(txtKodet.Text, -txtTrylletal.Text, False)

End Sub

Function Kod(tekst As String, trylletal As Integer, skalKodes As Boolean)
    Dim nyeCharVaerdier(tekst.Length) As Char

    For i As Integer = 0 To tekst.Length - 1
        Dim nytTal As Integer = findIndex(tekst(i), trylletal)

        If nytTal = -1 Then
            nyeCharVaerdier(i) = tekst(i)

        Else
            nyeCharVaerdier(i) = alfabet(nytTal)
        End If

    Next
    If skalKodes = True Then
        txtKodet.Text = nyeCharVaerdier
    Else
        txtDekodet.Text = nyeCharVaerdier
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function


Function findIndex(tegn As Char, trylletal As Integer) As Integer
    For alfabetTaeller As Integer = 0 To alfabet.Length - 1
        If tegn = alfabet(alfabetTaeller) Then
            Dim nytIndex As Integer = (alfabetTaeller + trylletal) Mod alfabet.Length
            Return nytIndex

        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub routine works.  However, the array you're using as a lookup table is declared as char but you're trying to fill it with strings.  If you had `Option Strict` on, you would have seen each string with a squiggly line underneath it, indicating an error.  Put a `c` after the closing " for each character and your sub routine will work.

```
Dim alfabet() As Char = {"a"c, "b"c, "c"c, "d"c, "e"c, "f"c, "g"c, "h"c, "i"c, "j"c, "k"c, "l"c, "m"c, "n"c, "o"c, "p"c, "q"c, "r"c, "s"c, "t"c, "u"c, "v"c, "w"c, "x"c, "y"c, "z"c, "æ"c, "ø"c, "å"c}
```

On a side note.  If you're not going to return any meaningful data declare the routine as a `Sub` instead of as a `Function`.  If you are going to return data, use the `As` clause to indicate what type of data will be returned.

Comment: The code works just fine when i have to increase each letter by one, and if it exceeds the index in my alphabet() array, it just starts over, due to the modulo. But in reverse it doesn't work, and the array gets below zero. So i don't think the alphabet array is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can cause that error is when an array index is too large or less than zero. Try running the program in Visual Studio. When it gets the error, display the value of all the variables in the line of code it stopped on. (Use the debug menu). You should see the problem then.

Comment: I know that it is less than zero, but i don't know how to prevent that?
It works just fine when i have to increase each letter by one, and if it exceeds the index in my alphabet() array, it just starts over, due to the modulo. But in reverse it doesn't work, and the array gets below zero.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if i add the length of my alfabet() array to the new indices that are negative - everything works fine :-)

```
if nytTal < 0 Then
nytTal += nytTal + alfabet.Length
End If
```